# What is the purpose of http_cache_hosts entry in app/etc/env.php?

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish, environment-variable

I have configured Varnish cache in the local Magento 2 environment and It is working fine.

I have added the below lines in the `app/etc/env.php` file.

```
'http_cache_hosts' => [
    [
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'port' => '6082'
    ]
]
```

What is the real purpose of adding this configuration in Magento 2 `env.php`?

What do these configurations do?

How it affects Magento? Please Help me Out....

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/varnish/use-varnish-cache.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make Magento aware of the Varnish servers, add the following section to `app/etc/env.php`. For Example:

```
'http_cache_hosts' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'host' => 'varnish-0',
      'port' => '80',
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
      'host' => 'varnish-1',
      'port' => '80',
    ),
  ),
```

In order to ensure the Varnish cache can be cleared, you must also add a node to your `env.php` to tell Magento how to communicate with Varnish

**I hope this will help**

Comment: If i don't add these lines in env.php, then Varnish cache won't work as expected in Magento Right ?

Comment: It is because If you want to flush the Varnish cache from the Magento backend, you need to add the Varnish server in your Magento config to http-cache-hosts.

Answer (score 1):

You can also put Varnish hots using bin/magento:

```
magento setup:config:set --http-cache-hosts=192.0.2.100,192.0.2.155:6081
```